# Como buscar duas palavras no mesmo campo Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia.

Tenho um campo em minha tabela chamado `tags`, gostaria de fazer uma busca, onde duas ou três palavras possam ser consideradas.

Exemplo: No campo `tags`, tenho algumas palavras, como "grátis", "cabines", "audiômetro"... com a consulta abaixo, meu resultado retorna vazio, mesmo com a palavra estando dentro do campo.

Como estou fazendo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Produtos 
WHERE Tags = 'Audiômetro' OR 'Impedanciômetro' OR 'OEA' OR 'BERA' OR 'Vectonistagmógrafo';
```

O meu resultado só aparece se eu tiver APENAS um item no campo "tags". Se eu colocar uma frase, por exemplo, não recebo resultados.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve usar a cláusula [**`IN`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Produtos 
WHERE Tags IN ('Audiômetro', 'Impedanciômetro', 'OEA', 'BERA', 'Vectonistagmógrafo');
```

**editado**

Considerando que o campo `Tags` contém mais de uma tag a consulta ficaria um pouco diferente, veja se o [**`REGEXP`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) facilita as coisas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Produtos 
WHERE Tags REGEXP 'Audiômetro|Impedanciômetro|OEA|BERA|Vectonistagmógrafo';
```

Comment: Ainda retornando vazio. No meu campo `tags`, separei as palavras por vírgula, mas ainda não tenho resultados

Comment: Se eu deixar uma palavra apenas no campo, ele me traz o resultado esperado. Mas preciso de mais palavras no mesmo campo.

Comment: seu campo `Tags` contém várias tags? tipo assim "OEA,BERA,Vectonistagmógraf"??

Comment: Exato. Preciso que ele liste os produtos, à partir da busca pelas tags.

Comment: tranks :p às vezes penso isso também

Comment: Atendeu, galera! Agradeço por vossa dedicação. Obrigado @rLinhares. Ficou perfeito!

Comment: Sensacional, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 6):

Antes de mais nada, o ideal seria se o texto das tags ficasse separado do campo, seria uma solução mais escalável.

Se quiser realmente usar busca textual, a solução passa por algo assim:

```
SELECT .... WHERE
     tags LIKE '%tag1%' AND
     tags LIKE '%tag2%'
```

e repete o AND quantas tags forem.

Aí tem outro problema pra resolver:

Se a busca for pela tag "Audio", você vai achar o campo "Audiometro", o que é indesejável.

A solução seria usar o separador do campo no `LIKE`:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE
      CONCAT( ',' , tags , ',' ) LIKE '%,tag1,%' ...
```

Esta complexidade toda serve para forçar a delimitação por virgulas, e o `CONCAT` para garantir que tenha uma no começo e uma no fim (para a primeira e última tags).

### `FIND_IN_SET`

Se o campo de tags puder ser separado pela vírgula, o MySQL tem uma função dedicada:

```
SELECT ... WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET( 'tag1', tags ) AND
    FIND_IN_SET( 'tag2', tags ) AND
    FIND_IN_SET( 'tag3', tags ) 
    ...
```

Em qualquer solução adotada, convém que você sempre normalize o armazenamento das tags, para retirar eventuais espaços, acertar acentos etc.

Comment: Já tinha visto essa solução, mas como pretendo lançar 10, 15 tags, achei que seria menos trabalhoso colocá-las num campo só.

Comment: ainda retornando vazio. Fiz o teste abaixo com o `REGEXP` e funcionou certinho. Obrigado pelo seu tempo! Você é o cara!

Comment: Pode ser algum detalhe bobo de sintaxe, de qq forma se tem algum erro na resposta é fundamental eu achar e corrigir pra nao deixar nada ensinando errado. Teria que ver seu código pra ver se o erro foi meu ou seu, mas nao daria pra fazer isso aqui na resposta. Qq coisa, se quiser, deixe um link para o pastebin nos comments que eu espio mais tarde.

Comment: Pode até ser erro meu aqui, não se martirize. Com certeza, eu devo ter implantado errado. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: De qq forma, eu recomendaria pensar num relacionamento de tabelas, em vez de armazenar em texto, pq quando você tiver muitas tags, começa a complicar. Busca em substring é lenta, seja com regex, like ou find_in_set

Comment: Entendo. Isso é possível acontecer. Vou estudar essa possibilidade.

Comment: Ainda na questão de _normalizar_ pode ser interessante armazenar no banco usando pipes "|" como separador e substituir na exibição assim vc sempre poder pesquisar com SELECT ... WHERE Tags LIKE `%termo|% ...